# CSS Resources load after Javascript?

Tags: css, networking, resources, loading

I noticed that CSS Resources are being loaded after JavaScript. The stylesheets are being included in the `<head>` tag, and we include all our JS scripts at the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the stylesheet we load an image:

```
body {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
}
```

Now the networks panel looks like this:
[image: An example showing Google Chrome's Networks panel]

As you notice the image is being loaded after the JavaScript, even though the CSS was declared before the JavaScript.

How can we make sure that we only load the javascript after the CSS resources have finished loading?

[For an example you can visit this page](http://iamapt.com/files/loading-example/) and inspect it with the networks panel.

Comment: Why would you need to apply this behaviour?

Comment: Fiddler reports that the CSS file is being loaded first on your site..

Comment: @Celt: the CSS file is indeed being loaded first, but I'd expect the external image to be loaded after the CSS, not after the JS.

Comment: Maybe the local files are loaded first then the external ones are?